# How to execute web requests in parallel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to execute this code in parallel? I tried to execute the execution in threads, but the requests are still being executed sequentially. I am new to parallel programming, I will be very happy for your help.

```
    public async Task<IList<AdModel>> LocalBitcoins_buy(int page_number)
    {
        IList<AdModel> Buy_ads = new List<AdModel>();
        string next_page_url;
        string url = "https://localbitcoins.net/buy-bitcoins-online/.json?page=" + page_number;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                JObject json = JObject.Parse(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
                next_page_url = (string) json["pagination"]["next"];
                int counter = (int) json["data"]["ad_count"];
                for (int ad_list_index = 0; ad_list_index < counter; ad_list_index++)
                {
                    AdModel save = new AdModel();
                    save.Seller = (string) json["data"]["ad_list"][ad_list_index]["data"]["profile"]["username"];
                    save.Give = (string) json["data"]["ad_list"][ad_list_index]["data"]["currency"];
                    save.Get = "BTC";
                    save.Limits = (string) json["data"]["ad_list"][ad_list_index]["data"]["first_time_limit_btc"];
                    save.Deals = (string) json["data"]["ad_list"][ad_list_index]["data"]["profile"]["trade_count"];
                    save.Reviews = (string) json["data"]["ad_list"][ad_list_index]["data"]["profile"]["feedback_score"];
                    save.PaymentWindow = (string) json["data"]["ad_list"][ad_list_index]["data"]["payment_window_minutes"];
                    Buy_ads.Add(save);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(page_number);
        return Buy_ads;
    }
```

Comment: if next_page_url is not null, you are requesting the same page number again and again. Does not this cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Why do you try to execute this parallel, what is your purpose of doing this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-use-parallel-invoke-to-execute-parallel-operations

Comment: I need to get data from 60 pages if I do this sequentially, it will take a lot of time. Therefore, I want to start a parallel process.

Comment: Do you want to run method `LocalBitcoins_buy` with different values of the parameter `page_number` in parallel? If so, please, post the method that you currently use to get data from the pages (the method that is used to get data from 60 pages)?

Comment: Yes, the code for receiving data from the pages is above, I changed it a little. I want to start a separate stream for each page so that all flows work in parallel, and then combine the received data from each stream into a common list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled and found this links [1](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/issues/175), [2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/901df51b-e121-4ead-b8a7-e553569f3d6a/parallel-with-web-request?forum=csharpgeneral). It seems that `WebRequest` cannot execute requests in parallel. Also I tried to send multiple requests in parallel using `WebRequest` and for some reasons `WebRequest` didn't make requests in parallel.

But when I used [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) class it did requests in parallel. Try to use `HttpClient` instead of `WebRequest` as Microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

**So, firstly, you should use `HttpClient` to make web request.**

---

**Then you can use the next approach to download pages in parallel:**

```
public static IList<AdModel> DownloadAllPages()
{
    int[] pageNumbers = getPageNumbers();
    // Array of tasks that download data from the pages.
    Task<IList<AdModel>>[] tasks = new Task<IList<AdModel>>[pageNumbers.Length];

    // This loop lauches download tasks in parallel.
    for (int i = 0; i < pageNumbers.Length; i++)
    {
        // Launch download task without waiting for its completion.
        tasks[i] = LocalBitcoins_buy(pageNumbers[i]);
    }

    // Wait for all tasks to complete.
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    // Combine results from all tasks into a common list.
    return tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Result).ToList();
}
```

Of course, you should add error handling into this method.

Comment: Thanks, pasted your code into my project. All requests continue to be executed synchronously.

Comment: @Clear Mind I tried to send multiple requests using WebRequest and provided method DownloadAllPages. For some reasons WebRequest didn't make requests in parallel. But when I used [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.0) class it did requests in parallel. Try to use HttpClient instead of WebRequest. Microsoft also [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) to use HttpClient. Please, let me know if HttpClient helps you.

Comment: @Clear Mind I googled and found this links [1](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/issues/175), [2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/901df51b-e121-4ead-b8a7-e553569f3d6a/parallel-with-web-request?forum=csharpgeneral). It seems that WebRequest cannot execute requests in parallel. Therefore try to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.0).

Comment: @Clear Mind I updated my post to include all required information.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you study this post carefully:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/walkthrough-accessing-the-web-by-using-async-and-await

It has a tutorial that is doing exactly what you want to do:  Downloading multiple pages simultaneously.

WebRequest does not work asynchronously with getResponse purposefully.  It has a second method:  getResponseAsync().

To get your toes wet with threading, you can also use the drop-in replacement for the foreach and for loops:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop